# Programmatically Translate View Pre-Honeycomb

Tags: android, android-layout

How can I programmatically translate an arbitrary view without using an animation (`android.view.animation.*`)?

API 11 introduced `setTranslationX` and `setTranslationY`, `setX` and `setY`, and `getMatrix`—all of which can be used to accomplish what I'm looking for. I cannot seem to find an equivalent on the prior API levels, however.

The `android.view.animation.TranslateAnimation` uses `getMatrix` in its implementation (as far back as API 4) but it was a private API throughout this time.

Is there any way to accomplish this without resorting to reflection?

Comment: That awkward moment when you're about to answer "use nineoldandroid"...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Favorited because I would love to be proven wrong on this one, but I ran into a similar wall when doing some Drag-n-Drop investigations awhile back.

I'm pretty sure you're stuck with `offsetTopAndBottom()` and `offsetLeftAndRight()` for moving a `View` around without an animation in early APIs.  The big downside here is that these methods actually modify the top/bottom/left/right values, so you have to do some pretty heavy tracking if you want to go back to where you started from.

Another option would be to simply use a `TranslateAnimation` with a VERY short duration and set to `fillAfter`...

Other options require subclassing, and still aren't pretty, like translating the `Canvas` the `View` draws on.  The problem here is you also have to create a parent that doesn't clip it's children so the view can draw outside its own bounds.

Comment: You can also subclass layout container class you use, override its onLayout method and set x/y/width/height from there to any values at any time for any view.

Comment: It's a crappy situation. The ironic thing is that I'm actually trying to animate these views' translation but through the Honeycomb API (http://nineoldandroids.com). I was hoping to provide a compatibility implementation of sorts directly in the library for pre-Honeycomb translation so that someone using the library didn't have to special case it in their own code. I tried the offset methods as you said but it is quite difficult tracking the original location and prevision keyframe location reliably. Reflection is looking better and better...

Comment: Have you managed to done that compability implementation? That would be totally awesome!

Comment: When TranslationAnimation is given 0 values for setTranslationX & setTranslationY, it animates back to its original position on the screen independent of what translations have already been done with it.

Comment: guys any solution for pre-Honeycomb translation?

Answer (score 11):

Yes, you can use TranslateAnimation. With fillAfter set to true your view will stay translated even after the animation ends. Here is an example:

```
TranslateAnimation anim=new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 20, 20);
anim.setFillAfter(true);
anim.setDuration(0);
yourView.startAnimation(anim);
```

Comment: This does work, unfortunately the views will stay at their original location which means click/touch targets won't move :(

Comment: its working but click will be at same place for pre-Honeycomb translation any solution ?

Comment: @Ram the only way is to create a custom ViewGroup and use it as a container for your transformed view, override its dispatchTouchEvent method and transform the touches accordingly. Anyway, now you can just drop the support for 2.x as these are outdated system versions. Starting with 3.x, there are built-in transformations that account for touches and everything else.

Answer (score 6):

Grishka's answer helped me a lot, works perfectly.  In order to animate the translation using the Honeycomb API with nineoldandroids, I set up a FloatEvaluator for the translation value and then used either setTranslationX on Honeycomb+ or the TranslateAnimation method.  Here is my code:

```
public class TranslationXEvaluator extends FloatEvaluator {

private View view;

public TranslationXEvaluator(View view) {
    this.view = view;
}

@Override
public Float evaluate(float fraction, Number startValue, Number endValue) {
    float translationX = super.evaluate(fraction, startValue, endValue);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        view.setTranslationX(translationX);
    } else {
        TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation(translationX, translationX, 0, 0);
        anim.setFillAfter(true);
        anim.setDuration(0);
        view.startAnimation(anim);
    }
    return translationX;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem. I was able to achieve the translation by manipulating the layoutparams, specifically the margins, of the views I wanted to translate. You can use negative values for the margins btw.

Comment: Best solution when you also want to move click/touch targets :)

Answer (score 1):

One alternative to TranslateAnimation is to subclass a View and translate the Canvas on dispatchDraw.
Something like:

```
 public class TranslateView extends View {

        private float mTranslationX = 0;
        private float mTranslationY = 0;
        private boolean mWillUseSDKTranslation = true;

        @Override
        protected void dispatchDraw(final Canvas canvas) {
            if (mWillUseSDKTranslation == false) {
                // keep track of the current state
                canvas.save(Canvas.MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG);
                // translate
                canvas.translate(mTranslationX, mTranslationY);
                // draw it
                super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
                // restore to the previous state
                canvas.restore();
            } else {
                super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
            }
        }

        public void setTranslationValue(final float aTranslationX, final float aTranslationY) {
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                mWillUseSDKTranslation = false;
                mTranslationX = aTranslationX;
                mTranslationY = aTranslationY;
                invalidate();
            } else {
                setTranslationX(aTranslationX);
                setTranslationY(aTranslationY);
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You also can try this code: https://github.com/BeyondAR/beyondar/blob/development/android/BeyondAR_Framework/src/com/beyondar/android/view/CustomLayout.java

Use the method setPosition.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround I found was to set negative margins using:

```
layoutParams.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
yourView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```