# change places of 3 buttons with action()

Tags: android

im making my first app, 
I need a way when you press a button(id=button2) the places of the buttons will change, if you press button 1,3 , the app will exit.
i made this:

```
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch(v.getId()){

    }

    int id = v.getId();
    if (id == R.id.button1) {
        action2();
    } else if (id == R.id.button2) {
        action1();
    } else if (id == R.id.button3) {
        action2();
    }
    }
private void action2() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    finish();
    System.exit(0);
}
private void action1() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    changingTextView.setText(+1);
    /* I need here a way to change the buttons places */

}
```

how can I make action1() to change the button places?
here is the main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.bluetap.FirstActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:minWidth="200dp"
    android:text="Press The White Button"
    android:textColor="@color/blue" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:minWidth="200dp"
    android:text="Press The White Button"
    android:textColor="@color/blue" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
    android:minWidth="200dp"
    android:text="Press The White Button"
    android:textColor="@color/blue" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/changingTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="95dp"
    android:text="0"
    android:textSize="60sp" />
```

thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

This should help you: [View.setTranslationX](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTranslationX%28float%29)

EDIT: and maybe [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8734001/programmatically-translate-view-pre-honeycomb)

Comment: well its my first app, I never used the setTranslation so its hard to me, can you help me a little bit?